# Does being under water affect Invisibility?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, invisibility, underwater

This came up with our game last night, with the players suggesting it would be easier to see a creature invisible under water, and I suggested that an aquatic caster might, know a version of the spell that is 'better' under water than the default.

So does casting invisibility under water affect it or not?

I can see answers for other systems

- pathfinder-1e [Invisibility under water](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122079/invisibility-under-water)
- dnd-5e [Are there any special rules governing invisibility underwater?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192056/are-there-any-special-rules-governing-invisibility-underwater)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Invisibility is affected by water

The spell description for [Invisibility](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/invisibility.htm) says:

> Of course, the subject is not magically silenced, and certain other conditions can render the recipient detectable (such as **stepping in a puddle**).

Being fully immersed under water is in a way just a more extreme version of stepping in a puddle: your invisible form displaces the water, and the resulting empty space in the water is visible, like an air bubble under water would be.

The *Rules Compendium* also addresses how this works on p. 77 (Thanks to [@Peregrin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/60054/peregrin); note that the rules compendium [cannot change the core rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/does-the-rules-compendium-overrule-the-core-books), so read this more as a clarifying statement of intent):

> An invisible target in the water displaces water, revealing its location. The invisible target is still hard to see and benefits from concealment

Comment: The Rules Compendium (p 77) directly address this. _"An invisible target in the water displaces water, revealing its location. The invisible target is still hard to see and benefits from concealment."_

Comment: @Peregrin, thank you I will add this!

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, _invisibility underwater_ is also adressed in the DMG (p 93): _"An invisible creature displaces water and leaves a
visible, body-shaped “bubble” where the water was displaced. The
creature still has concealment (20% miss chance), but not total
concealment (50% miss chance)."_